# How to change EditText Done button on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'd love to do that in XML but code will do if nothing else is left. I want to change default actionDone button color on Android wear.

[image: Done button]

Comment: In easy way you can not change this because this color is keyboard app and you can not change theme of other app

Comment: You need to create your custom keyboard to do this

Comment: Unfortunate... thanks tho!

Comment: Create custom key board.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these repository for custom keyboard

https://github.com/appfour/AndroidWearKeyboardApi,

https://github.com/idoideas/Wear-Keyboard